# How tell if W.I.F token exists? - Best approach

Tags: wif

I am using Windows Identity foundation.  In one of the sites protected by W.I.F, there is a user registration view, which anonymous users can browse to.  At this point, i would like to see in my registration controller if a W.I.F token currently exists:

I was going to do it like this:

```
public bool HasWifToken(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = httpContextBase.User.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return claimsIdentity.Claims.Count > 0;
        }
```

But is there a better way to see if you have a live token?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is this:

```
var hasWifToken = httpContextBase.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

If you're using WIF, `IsAuthenticated` will tell you whether a token exists (i.e., the user is signed in).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use IsAuthenticated in IdentityMode.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.

Interestingly, the way it is set is very much along your approach - essentially it checks if the claims.Count > 0!